# Header and footer fail to load with SSL and custom links

Tags: templates, headers, ssl, footer

I have an existing site that I am now trying to secure, but I'm running into problems with the header and footer on the pages that are accessed via custom links in the menu. When I try to access a custom link (such as http://mywebsite.com/SomeNonWordPressComponent), the content loads, but the header and footer render as:

```
Moved Permanently

The document has moved here (https://localhost/common/header.php).
```

The header and footer on regular WordPress pages render perfectly fine.

What do I have to change so that the header and footer will render correctly for custom pages?

---

Things I've tried so far:

- set `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` to begin with `https`.
- click the "Save Changes" button on the Permalinks page.
- manually add to my WordPress root directory's .htaccess this extra rewrite rule:

```
     RewriteCond     %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteRule     (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Still getting the redirect (as above) for the header and footer.

Also:
the path `common/header.php` actually exists up one level from the wordpress root directory. Tried a symlink in wordpress to `/path/to/webroot/common` bt that does not seem to work, either.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your WordPress dashboard and navigate to `Settings >> General`, then change the `WordPress Address (URL)` and the `Site Address (URL)` from HTTP to HTTPS. Then hit `Save Changes` button.

If your problem is not fixed yet then go to `Settings >> Permalinks` and hit `Save Changes` button again. It'll re-generate your `.htaccess` file. Sometimes the `.htaccess` cause some unusual problems. I'm just making sure that its fine.

Comment: I tried changing the URLs to use HTTPS yesterday but it had no impact. I'll try the `Settings >> Permalinks` change later today, if I have time.

Comment: Well, I tried the "Save Changes" button but that did not work.